# How to read, clean and append START and END token to a csv-like file?

Tags: python, csv

I am working on a tutorial which reads a csv file :

```
# Read the data and append SENTENCE_START and SENTENCE_END tokens

with open('data/reddit-comments-2015-08.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    reader.next()
    # Split full comments into sentences
    sentences = itertools.chain(*[nltk.sent_tokenize(x[0].decode('utf- 
        8').lower()) for x in reader])
    # Append SENTENCE_START and SENTENCE_END
    sentences = ["%s %s %s" % (sentence_start_token, x, 
                               sentence_end_token) for x in sentences]
    print "Parsed %d sentences." % (len(sentences))
```

but get the following error:

```
sentences = itertools.chain(*[nltk.sent_tokenize(x[0].decode('utf-8').lower()) for x in reader])
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

Can anyone help me with that. I am new in nltk.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your `csv` file?

Comment: I have never seen a CSV read like that but maybe you have a blank line at the end of the file? What happens with `sentences = itertools.chain(*[nltk.sent_tokenize(x[0].decode('utf-8').lower()) for x in reader if x])`?

Comment: `x[0]` is valid unless the row is empty.

Comment: It is from https://github.com/dennybritz/rnn-tutorial-rnnlm/blob/master/RNNLM.ipynb. I have tried it with both python 2, and 3.

Comment: @pault, the csv file is availabe at https://github.com/dennybritz/rnn-tutorial-rnnlm/tree/master/data. I am not sure how I can show the csv file here.

Comment: Tthe csv file is availabe at github.com/dennybritz/rnn-tutorial-rnnlm/tree/master/data. I am not sure how I can show the csv file here.

Comment: That's not exactly a cvs file but you can it as one.

Comment: Thanks @alvas. When I read this csv file I get weird output. Here is an example of the output: <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://asset...
4      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avata...
5      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avata...
6      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avata...
7      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avata...
8      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://githu...
9      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://user-...
10     <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://...
11     <link crossorigin="anonymous"

Comment: and because of that, it does not recognise df['body']!

Comment: You should download the file from https://github.com/dennybritz/rnn-tutorial-rnnlm/blob/master/data/reddit-comments-2015-08.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not exactly a cvs file but you can it as one.

With `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('reddit-comments-2015-08.csv', sep='\0')
```

[out]:

```
body
0   I joined a new league this year and they have ...
1   In your scenario, a person could just not run ...
2   They don't get paid for how much time you spen...
3   I dunno, back before the August update in an A...
4   No, but Toriyama sometimes would draw himself ...
```

Then to remove the starting and trailing spaces:

```
df['body'][:100].astype(str).apply(str.strip)
```

Next, you see that you have weird XML escaped symbols (e.g. `&gt`, `&lt`, etc.) in the text, so before tokenization, you have to unescape them:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize.util import xml_unescape

df = pd.read_csv('reddit-comments-2015-08.csv', sep='\0')
df['body'].astype(str).apply(str.strip).apply(xml_unescape)
```

Now you can do the tokenization:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize.util import xml_unescape

df = pd.read_csv('reddit-comments-2015-08.csv', sep='\0')
df['body'].astype(str).apply(str.strip).apply(xml_unescape).apply(word_tokenize)
```

To add the START and END token, simply do:

```
df['tokens'] = ['START'] + df['body'].astype(str).apply(str.strip).apply(xml_unescape).apply(word_tokenize) + ['END']
```